# What's the difference between a static member variable and a namespace variable?

Tags: c++, class, oop, namespaces

Whit is the difference between 1 and 2?

1:

```
namespace Foo {
    int bar;
}
```

2:

```
class Foo {
public:
    static int bar;
}
```

If `bar` is a function, then the difference is that `static class member` can access class `private` members.

But sometimes we just need to store a `constant` for example. Then we have a choice.

Is there any difference between these two?

And what would be the reason to choose one over another.

I have searched this, and I am surprised there's no answer already on the web.

Comment: I specifically said this is NOT a function. Yet someone voted to close use a "function" question.

Comment: Well, we have [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793334/c-static-vs-namespace-vs-singleton) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802218/namespaces-vs-static-classes) and multiple others.

Comment: Usually we use static to keep the value consistent in all it's instances... If the value is going to stay constant then I see no point using it...

Comment: For constants, the only reason for choosing one over the other is "association" imho. If the constant is directly related to the class, it should be a static const(!) member. If it is a "global constant" leave it in namespace scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Just in terms of the object you're declaring

The namespace declaration defines an object uniquely for the whole program. If you put that in a header file, including the header from two different source files would produce a multiple definition linker error.

The class static declaration asks the linker to share one object among all source files.

#### As for class vs. namespace

Classes and namespaces are completely different things. A class describes how to form an object. Class templates may also be used to form metaprograms. But a class should not be used merely to group things inside a scope, such that the class is never instantiated. That is the job of a namespace.

If you want to share the object among several sources, do this:

```
// Foo.h
namespace Foo {

extern int bar; // declaration

}

// Foo.cpp
namespace Foo {

int bar = 2; // definition

}
```

If the object is a constant, the definition is unnecessary as long as you never require `bar` to have an address in memory.

Answer (score 1):

As there are good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434937/namespace-functions-versus-static-methods-on-a-class), I want to add some importand difference:

If you need to declare global variables with certain types and a unique name you can go with static variables in templates classes. This is not possible with namespaces (at least not now).

```
template <class T>
struct my_variable_name {
  static T value;
};


my_variable_name<int>::value=7;

my_variable_name<float>::value=5.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Big difference. Apart from literal difference, they are different in the following way:

1. A class is like a model, to reflect some state or behavior, to generate objects. A namespace is just for name isolation, and cannot be used for constructing objects.
2. A namespace can be declared as anonymous. A class cannot.